# Modify Excel chart axis properties by python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, excel-charts

I created the secondary axis Chart, but I can not remove the y-axis line.

However, the code works for single axis chart.

Code:

```
headings = ['Province', 'Voice_Users', 'RATE']
data = [
    province_List,
    PCS_List,
    PCS_List_Rate,
]
workPCS_Fail_prv.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
workPCS_Fail_prv.write_column('A2', data[0])
workPCS_Fail_prv.write_column('B2', data[1])
workPCS_Fail_prv.write_column('C2', data[2])

column_chart2 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

column_chart2.set_legend({'position': 'bottom'})

column_chart2.add_series({
    'name':       '=PCS_Fail_prv!$B$1',
    'categories': '=PCS_Fail_prv!$A$2:$A$32',
    'values':     '=PCS_Fail_prv!$B$2:$B$32',
})

# Create a new column chart. This will use this as the secondary chart.
line_chart2 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

line_chart2.add_series({
    'name':       '=PCS_Fail_prv!$C$1',
    'categories': '=PCS_Fail_prv!$A$2:$A$32',
    'values':     '=PCS_Fail_prv!$C$2:$C$32',
    'y2_axis':    True,
    'line': {'color': 'orange', 'width': 2.5}
})

# Combine the charts.
column_chart2.combine(line_chart2)

column_chart2.set_title({  'name': 'Affected User',
                        'name_font':{'name':'Calibri(Body)','size':14}})

column_chart2.set_x_axis({ 'line': {'none': True},
                            'num_font':{'size':9,'name':'Calibri(Body)' },
                            'name_font':  {'name': 'Calibri(Body)','size':9}})

column_chart2.set_y_axis({'line': {'none': True},
                            'num_font':{'size':9,'name':'Calibri(Body)'},
                            'name_font': {'name':'Calibri(Body)','size':9}})                
column_chart2.set_y_axis({
    'major_gridlines': {
        'visible': True,
        'line': {'color' : '#CCCCCC'}
    },
})                                  
line_chart2.set_y2_axis({'line': {'none': True},
            'num_font':{'size':9,'name':'Calibri(Body)' },
            'name_font':  {'name': 'Calibri(Body)','size':9}})
```

The code does not work for the y-axis as it can be seen in the attached photo:

[image]

I want the axis like the below chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to see what is wrong here since the example isn't complete and the images don't match the program.

However, setting `'line': {'none': True}` in `set_??_axis()` should work to turn off the axes. For example:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook  = Workbook('chart_combined.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a format for the headings.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ['Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2']
data = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

# Create a new column chart. This will use this as the primary chart.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Configure the data series for the primary chart.
chart.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$B$1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})

# Create a new column chart. This will use this as the secondary chart.
line_chart2 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Configure the data series for the secondary chart. We also set a
# secondary Y axis via (y2_axis).
line_chart2.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$C$1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7',
    'y2_axis':    True,
})

# Combine the charts.
chart.combine(line_chart2)

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'X Axis'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Y1 Axis',        'line': {'none': True}})
line_chart2.set_y2_axis({'name': 'Y2 Axis', 'line': {'none': True}})

# Hide the legend for clarity.
chart.set_legend({'none': True})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet
worksheet.insert_chart('E2', chart)
```

Output:[image]